# boost assertion failed message using quantile function

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to using Boost 1.66.0 version to calculate Quantile of a chi squared distribution through the following piece of code :

```
boost::math::chi_squared chisqdist(Tcopnu);
```

Tcopnu : are the degree of freedoms in Chi Squared Distribution above.

Next I use the Quantile function (Inverse CDF function) of boost to get quantile at specific probability p through the following code :

double quantile = boost::math::quantile(chisqdist,  uniformNum);

However, I get the following error message while using the quantile function :

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::assertion_failed_msg(char const *,char const *,char const *,char const *,long)" (?assertion_failed_msg@boost@@YAXPBD000J@Z) referenced in function "public: long double const & __thiscall boost::array<long double,171>::operator[](unsigned int)const " (??A?$array@O$0KL@@boost@@QBEABOI@Z)
```

I have used all the required following header file while using these functions from boost :

```
boost/math/distributions/detail/generic_quantile.hpp
boost/math/tools/roots.hpp
boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp
```

I have spent fair bit of time resolving this error but was unsuccessful, It would be great if someone can provide any tips.

Comment: The error is a linker error, not a compiler error.  The linker cannot find the function that your code is calling.

Comment: See the [Boost.Assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html) documentation. If you define `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER` you're also expected to provide a definition for `boost::assertion_failed_msg`. Maybe Boost.Math enables this, and you're missing the header where the definition is.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from a missing `::boost::assertion_failed_msg` function that is supposed to be supplied by user to manually handle assertion message produced by `BOOST_ASSERT_MSG` macro. Its use is triggered  when `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER` macro is defined before including boost (assert) headers. See [Boost.Assert documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html).